# Contact page provides weak guidance on providing feedback and making feature requests

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions, contact, feature-request-process

https://stackoverflow.com/contact mentions "Feedback" only under the unclear heading "Jobs Support" near the end and there is no mention of "feature requests" or "making contributions" to the platform. A sentence should be added near the top explaining what to do.

This itself is a feature request and the heading "Ask a public question" of this form casts doubts that this is the right place as this is not a question but just telling you that something is missing. Only proceeded as I see other feature requests under "similar questions", there is engagement with these questions and they have not been closed. Seeing "feature-request" as a possible tag supports that this is the right thing to do but it isn't clear on the steps to this place.

Suggestions:

1. Change this existing text:

   > If you have a question about a Stack Exchange site, the best place to ask is...

   to -->

   > If you have a question about a Stack Exchange site or have a suggestion how to improve the site, the best place to ask is...
2. On meta, implement [Bug reports and feature requests are not "questions"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217716/bug-reports-and-feature-requests-are-not-questions)

Comment: re your second paragraph: see the [feature-request wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/feature-request/info)

Comment: @RobertLongson The text before `-->` is the existing text on the site. The text after `-->` is what I suggest instead.

Comment: Where do we have the text "Ask a question" on the site? I give you the "ask a public question" is non-sense on Meta, or any not SO site for that matter.

Comment: @rene Thanks, I missed the word "public". Corrected.

Comment: The HTML `&rarr;` [works](https://pmortensen.eu/world/FixedStrings.php?OverflowStyle=Native) as well (Unicode "→").

Comment: Yes, the Q&A model is a poor fit for meta sites, as the proverbial [square peg in a round hole](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/square_peg_in_a_round_hole#Noun). It was only because [Atwood didn't want to put any more work into it than necessary](https://blog.codinghorror.com/meta-is-murder/) (as *nearly* the same software could be used). In 2020, [Chipps](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/139284/sara-chipps) toyed with the idea of replacing it with something else (I don't have the references at hand, but they should be there somewhere), but nothing came of it (as far as we know).

Answer (score 4):

No, let's not change the wording. The Stack Exchange Network is collection of sites that follow the Question and Answer model and the underlying engine is optimized for that.

All interactions go in the form of a Question and hopefully just one Answer. If you deviate from that by adding more fluff, like 'or request feature', then we have become a *Q/A and Request Feature* site. Next up: Where do I post Bugs? On the *Q/A and Request Feature and Bug Report* site. In 6 to 8 weeks we have all 40,000 tags listed in that title.

If anything, the word "public" can be removed as that is only relevant when you are on Stack Overflow and member of a team. It has no purpose and obviously leads to unneeded confusion. That can be fixed in one go, for all 170 sites and their metas.

Comment: Are you saying that the assumption in the question body, namely that meta is where feature requests should be made, is wrong? There are plenty of other questions and answers suggesting this is the place. If not, this then still leaves the core issue in the title.

Comment: @JoachimWagner Meta is [*the primary feedback and discussion space for issues that relate to the sites on the Stack Exchange Network and the software that powers this platform.*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and that also includes feature requests, bugs and support **questions**. We don't need the **strong** guidance on the contact page you suggest because you're missing out on several categories. And I don't fancy duplicating all direction guidance on the contact page as that is not where that page is for.